# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, airflow

I have been trying to fetch packages of **airflow** software through the command "**pip install airflow[all]**" but it's showing a message as:

*Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1*

The Error displayed:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools__init__.py", line 51,
>   in findout = cls._find_packages_iter(convert_path(where))
>         File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\util.py", line 126, in convert_path
>            raise ValueError, "path '%s' cannot end with '/'" % pathname
>       ValueError: path 'src/' cannot end with '/'

Any suggestions to resolve this issue?

Comment: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` did the trick for me when I wanted to install Astropy. Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289107/installation-of-astropy-in-casa).

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting error using pip.

Would request you to download package and manually install.

Download tar file and extract it. Go to that folder from command line where setup.py file resides.

Enter following command on command line prompt.

```
python setup.py install
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify your steps a bit more? Where do you go to download and manually install the package when the installation page just describes installation via pip? [installation page](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/installation.html)

Comment: let's take an example of numpy. Download zip package from https://pypi.org/project/numpy/ , extract zip file and you can see setup.py inside it. Once you extract, run the above given command using sudo permission. Hope this helps !

Comment: haha would you mind using airflow as the example? Numpy package has a download link on the main page, so the download step you described is a bit more intuitive there. I think the challenge with this problem is when the available package installation documentation only provides pip instructions

Comment: (not exactly related to this QA) A very similar error is thrown from `setup.py` file of [`v1-10-stable` branch](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/setup.py#L124) since it conflicts with `async` keyword of `Python 3.7.x`. They did fix it in [`Airflow-2713`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/commit/e38a4e5d3064980abd10b8afa6918ab9f10dd8a2) but I'm confused as to why did this *2-month old fix* was left out of [`PyPi` release](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/#history)