# Installation of astropy in casa

Tags: python, installation, astropy

I am trying to install astropy into CASA 4.3.1 on my Mac. I'm following the instructions found [here](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/install.html#installing-astropy-into-casa). But after running `pip.main(['install', 'astropy', '--user'])`, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

EDIT:

After using

```
import pip._internal
pip._internal.main(['install', 'astropy', '--user'])
```

The installation starts but stops with the error:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/
```

Comment: Which is the version of `pip` that you have? Can you share the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: @JorgeLavín pip 10.0.1. I haven't run anything else.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this. The reason pip.main was moved is that pip is not intended to be used as a library. If you need to use pip to install packages why can't you do it at the command-line? In your answer below you did exactly that to upgrade pip and setuptools. Just do the same for astropy or any other package.

Comment: @Iguananaut Well that's what the guide about installing Astropy into CASA I linked in the question says.

Comment: Yeah I see that now. Sorry it misled you, I think it's a little out of date. I opened an issue on the issue tracker to update that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and I'm sharing it in case anyone else has the same problem in the future. The steps are the following. After having followed the procedure I mentioned in the question, without the final step, one needs to run the following command in the terminal:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

then open casa and `import pip._internal` and finally run `pip._internal.main(['install', 'astropy', '--user'])`.

Comment: This is a headache related to pip not supporting non-command-line usage.  See related issues https://github.com/astropy/astroquery/issues/1219 and https://github.com/radio-astro-tools/casa-python/issues/19.  I'm still trying to work out the best general (version-independent) approach to this...